# Подскажите как сделать бота в телеграме на python, который будет продавать каждому покупателю уникальный товар

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram, интернет-магазин

То есть к примеру у меня есть 5 промокодов, и человек решил купить один в боте, он оплатил, и ему пришел один из этих промокодов, но следующий покупатель получит уже другой промокод, т.к. первый купил другой пользователь. Ума не приложу как это можно реализовать, может быть через базу данных?
мне нужна только логика вычеркивания товара после его покупки, все остальное (Оплату и прочее), умею сам. Заранее очень благодарен!(Пишу на python API-aiogram, можно и telebot)

Comment: Сделать в бд флажок типа `куплено` или просто удалить из бд товар

Comment: Вы же считай на свой вопрос ответили `мне нужна логика вычеркивания товара после его покупки`

Comment: да, но как мне это сделать автоматически?

Comment: Ну вы же как-то отлавливает момент покупки товара? Ну вот тогда и удаляйте